# Foreach loop through two data sets and use same loop index for both

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, twig

I have users with `activities`.

Each activity has got some data and also a `startDate`.

Now I need to do something with the data on every single day. Beginning at the `startDate` of the first `activity`. So I started doing it in [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) but I can also change the logic (array) in PHP.

So I thought begin to loop over every day

```
{% if start_date is null %}
    {% set start_date = activities.first.startTime|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% endif %}

{% set end_date = date('now') %}

{% for index, date in range(start_date|date('U'), end_date|date('U'), 86400 ) %}

    {{ dump(date|date('d-m-Y')) }}

    {# Now the next line with if else is not working #}
    {# cause I don't know in activities how to be in #}
    {# the right loop position, like:                #}
    {# activities.first, activities.second, ...      #}

    {% if date|date('d-m-Y') ==  activities.startTime|date('d-m-Y') %}
        {{ dump(activity) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ dump(date|date('d-m-Y')) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

So in the above I would get every day which I do need but on those days I find in this loop

```
{% for activity in activities %}
    {{ dump(activity.startTime|date('d-m-Y')) }}    
{% endfor %}
```

I need to change that daily data. Thinking about changing the activities array keys to the date just seems very wrong. What would be the best and "right" way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your questions correctly.... You can mix if statements and for loops in twig - place this in your date range loop.

```
{% for activity in activities if activity.startTime|date('d-m-Y') == date|date('d-m-Y') %}
    {{ dump(activity) }}
{% else %}
    No activities on {{ date|date('d-m-Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```